# /boot vs /startup

Tags: discussion, tags

The distinction between the tags [boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) and [startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/startup) isn't very clear. The tag wiki excerpt for [boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) reads

> This tag covers both bootloader issues (what happens before the operating system starts) and the starting up of the operating system.

However, I think since this excerpt was written almost two years ago we've mostly been using [boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) for bootloader issues (up to loading the kernel) and [startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/startup) for the OS startup (`init`, rc scripts and so on). I think we should make this distinction official, and retag the few questions that will then be mistagged. Any opposition?

Also, on which side of the fence do initrd issues fall?

Comment: Do we really need two separate tags for this? The [/boot] tag wiki covers both (include initrd/initramfs/init). They're both pretty broad/ambiguous and need (IMO) at least one other tag to be useful.

Comment: As you can [see](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/8187/revisions) I'm familiar with the content of the tag wiki. With hindsight, I think it was a mistake to lump it all in a single tag, and current usage (both mine and others') is to use [tag:boot] for what happens before the kernel is loaded and [tag:startup] for what happens after the root device is mounted, with some fluctuatation for what happens in between. I agree that most questions will need another tag, such as “[tag:startup] [tag:solaris] how do I run a service at boot time?”, but that's the case of most questions in general.

Comment: Your last example is a good illustration of the problem: "**startup** How do I run a service at **boot** time?" I'm not sure trying to retag for the "U&L meaning of these words" is worth the effort.

Comment: @Mat But I'm not proposing to retag: according to my admittedly non-scientific eyeball estimate, most posts already follow this distinction in their tagging. I'm proposing to make this distinction official in the tag wiki, and retag the few outliers.

Answer (score 7):

This proposal seems fine to me.

I don't see a huge problem with putting initrd issues in *both* categories when applicable.